# Check whether if a class is a template class or not

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to detect whether a class is a template class or a simple class at compile time?

Eg:

```
class A
{
    public:
    void GetValue()
    {
        return 10 (compile time check? "": "+ 10"); // just an example
    }
};

class B : public A
{
};

template <class T>
class C : public A
{
};
```

Comment: How about using `typeid(x).name()`, if it has `<` things in it then it's template.

Comment: I want it to work on compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a traits for that:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_type_templated : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct is_type_templated<C<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/hFTrhy)

Note that it doesn't handle templated value (as `std::array<T, N>`).